# comparing values in a column in awk

Tags: unix, awk

How can I compare the values in one column and do some action after that? I want to compare the values of first column and when it changes insert a new line with zero values. For simplicity I need to write similar code as I have written in MATLAB, in AWK:

```
    for i=1:size(picks,1)-1
   if picks(i,1)~=picks(i+1,1)
     i
   end
end
```

input:

```
631 4892    1.640   0.0090  6796
631 4941    1.646   0.0090  6796
636 2121    0.860   0.0950  7013
636 2162    0.872   0.0890  7013
```

output:

```
631 4892    1.640   0.0090  6796
631 4941    1.646   0.0090  6796
631   9999    7013    0       0
636 2121    0.860   0.0950  7013
636 2162    0.872   0.0890  7013
```

Thanks for helps.

Comment: It would be helpful to show us some input and desired output. Have you given this a try in awk yourself? Please [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: @TomFenech I added an example. actually I tried to use arrays and read helps about that, but it was not successful.

Comment: How do you calculate the `9999` and the `7013` ?

Comment: 99999 is a constant value and 7013 is the 5th column in next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of comparing the current first column with the previous one, that was stored. If they differ, we print a new line with the previous col1 together with `0`:

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && $1!=prev {print prev, 0} {prev=$1}1' file
631 4892    1.640   0.0090  6796
631 4941    1.646   0.0090  6796
631 0
636 2121    0.860   0.0950  7013
636 2162    0.872   0.0890  7013
```